# recycler view is supposed to create buttons from the double-array provided to it. the recycler view shows up empty instead. no idea why

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

as for what i have tried to solve the problem, created multiple adapters with slight code changes i thought might fix the problem, created new button layouts. added toasts to see if the double array i was talking about has even been received by the results page.(it has).these are just some I remember.

Also, I'm a newbie to android. so...

Anyways, I have an image which might be easier to understand -
start from the bottom left tab's bottom comments...

[android studio screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz1tI.png)

[this is the new screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMvp4.png)

[this is the code where the problem finally was solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EkRq.png)

code added below too.

This is where the problem starts. I think...

results page class -

```
package com.kenetic.calculator_practice

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.view.isEmpty
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.kenetic.calculator_practice.databinding.ActivityResultPageBinding
import com.kenetic.calculator_practice.databinding.ResultPageTestingBinding

class ResultPage : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var resRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var binding : ResultPageTestingBinding

    companion object{ var LIST = "list" }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result_page)
        //resRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.results_recyler_view)

        resRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.test_recycler_view_one)
        val ListToSend = intent.extras?.getDoubleArray(LIST)!!.toList().toDoubleArray()
        resRecyclerView.adapter = ResultsAdapter(this,ListToSend)

        if (resRecyclerView.isEmpty()) {
            if (ListToSend.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "list and view empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, ("only view empty "+ListToSend.size.toString()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            //TODO - returning only view empty -_- That makes 0 sense.
            // any idea why the view is empty if the list isn't? cause I have been searching
            // the required conditions for a view to be empty and found almost nothing useful
        }
    }
}
```

Results adapter class -

```
package com.kenetic.calculator_practice

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class ResultsAdapter (
    private val context:Context,
    private val dataSet : DoubleArray) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultsAdapter.ResultViewHolder>() {

    class ResultViewHolder(view:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val textButton : Button = view.findViewById(R.id.result_button_test)
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ResultViewHolder {
        val buttonView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.test_button_layout,parent,false)
        makeToast()
        return ResultViewHolder(buttonView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ResultViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textButton.text = dataSet[position].toString()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataSet.size

    fun makeToast(){
        Toast.makeText(context,dataSet[1].toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }//TODO even this isn't getting called -_-
}
```

button layout - file name - test_button_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/result_button_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</GridLayout>
```

And finally, this is where the buttons are supposed to be visible.
Recycler view xml file - name - activity_result_page.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/test_recycler_view_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

any form of help would be much appriciated. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Adapter` will never call `onCreateViewHolder` if it is empty, meaning `currentDataSet = dataSet` will never get called. Thus your adapter will never contain any data to display.

So you can do two things

remove `currentDataSet` and just use `dataSet`, your initializing the `Adapter` with it anyways.

OR

create a setter inside your `Adapter`

```
fun submitArray(doubleArray : DoubleArray){
   dataSet = doubleArray
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and call it when you have new data to display.

Comment: Ok, I removed the current dataset variable. it shows no error. yet, the recycler view is empty. I made an if statement in the results page to make a toast if the view is empty and then to display the length of the dataset provided to it. it returned "empty" followed by the length of the array (not zero). so, if the array is being passed, then why is the adapter class not running the onCreate? even in the above image I added, why won't it run the onCreate? I know it is not running because I added a toast there too which didn't get executed. basically, why is it empty?

Comment: Can you edit you provided code above to reflect the changes you have made?

Comment: yes, just made the changes. also, a new screenshot image has been added on the top. thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you make your `RecyclerView` a fixed size not 0dp, 0dp but like 150dp x 150dp and change its background to another color like blue, in the xml.  So you can see if its creating room for items when the app is running.`RecyclerView` + `ConstraintLayout`s can be sketchy sometimes, says one thing in the previews but acts completely differently on the device.

Comment: I did that. it didn't work. the recycler view was there but, empty. the list wasn't the problem this time either. after that I deleted a few xml files that I had earlier used for testing purposes. then, deleted a few unused imports. and suddenly, it now works. I still have no idea how but, atleast it works now. cool. anyways, I have added the final working code some where near the top. the third link.